# Windows 7 won't close programs even in task manager

Tags: windows-7, firefox, skype, task-manager

Last week I noticed this happening for the first time. Firefox froze up and wouldn't load any new pages. The internet was working fine but the browser was stuck. So I closed the window and when I tried to open it again I got a notification that it was still running. I opened up task manager to try and shut it down manually but even after I hit end task several times it wouldn't work. I restarted the computer and went about my business without issue for a few days and then last night it started acting up again.

I uninstalled Firefox, restarted the computer, and used Chrome to reinstall it. When I opened Chrome, I noticed another strange thing. Instead of one Chrome file in task manager it had upwards of five or six Chrome programs running at once even though I only had a single tab open on a single window. I reinstalled Firefox and didn't have any issues for the evening but now this morning it's started up again. The Firefox program won't end, now the Skype program won't end either, and Chrome has five files showing up in task manager. I read a couple other questions and tried to open the command prompt to see if I could shut things down that way but the window opens for about a second than disappears. How do I make this stop? I'm having to restart my computer multiple times a day just to be able to get work done!

Comment: You can perform the clean boot in windows

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you can't force-quit Skype or FF.  I'm having a similar problem.  But the reason Chrome has more than one item in that list is it uses separate processes instead of just separate threads, like FF.  Basically, separate processes means that the OS knows that 2 things are running concurrently, and can help manage it.  Separate threads mean that the OS sees it more or less as 1 process, but the process may have concurrent code running that it is managing itself.  Chrome uses a new process for each tab, so that is why you see it multiple times. http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models